# Grid DFS visualization

Tags: java, swing, delay, repaint

Hello guys I am working on a project where I am trying to create a maze generator. 
So far I have a gird that is a 2D array of a Cell class and a JPanel that paints the grid to a JFrame and a function which uses Depth first Search to visit each Cell in the grid.
When the Cell has been visited the Cell color changes to black on the grid. 
My problem is the repaint on the grid is too fast is there anyway I can slow the time or set a timer to repaint after a number of seconds. Here is the code below

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Stack;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class Maze extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private Cell [][] maze;
    private int dims;
    private Stack<Cell> S = new Stack<Cell>();
    private SecureRandom num = new SecureRandom();
    Timer t;

    public Maze(int din)
    {
        dims = din;
        maze = new Cell[dims][dims];        
    }

    public void generator()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0;j < maze[0].length; j++)
            {
                maze[i][j] = new Cell(i,j);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean checkAll()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0;j < maze[0].length; j++)
            {
                if(!maze[i][j].visited)
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void adjlist()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0;j < maze[0].length; j++)
            {
                if(i+1 >= 0 && i+1 < dims)
            {
                maze[i][j].neighbor.add(maze[i+1][j]);

            }
            if(i-1 >= 0 && i-1 < dims)
            {
                maze[i][j].neighbor.add(maze[i-1][j]);          
            }
            if(j-1 >= 0 && j-1 < dims)
            {
                maze[i][j].neighbor.add(maze[i][j-1]);          
            }
            if(j+1 >= 0 && j+1 < dims)
            {
                maze[i][j].neighbor.add(maze[i][j+1]);          
            }
            }
        }
    }

    public void DFS(Cell x)
    {
        if (!checkAll() && !maze[x.row][x.column].visited) 
        {
            S.push(x);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(S.toArray()));
            maze[x.row][x.column].visited = true;
            int randnum = num.nextInt(maze[x.row][x.column].neighbor.size());
            Cell temp1 = maze[x.row][x.column].neighbor.get(randnum);
            if (!maze[temp1.row][temp1.column].visited) 
            {
                DFS(maze[temp1.row][temp1.column]);
            } 
            else if (maze[x.row][x.column].neighbor.isEmpty()) 
            {
                S.pop();
                maze[S.peek().row][S.peek().column].visited = false;
                DFS(S.pop());
            } 

            else 
            {
                if(S.size()-1 == 0)
                    return;
                Cell temp = null;
                for (Cell c : maze[x.row][x.column].neighbor) 
                {
                    if (!maze[c.row][c.column].visited) 
                    {
                        temp = c;
                        DFS(temp);                  
                    }
                }
                if (temp == null) {
                    S.pop();
                    maze[S.peek().row][S.peek().column].visited = false;
                    DFS(S.pop());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        for (int row = 0; row < maze.length; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < maze[0].length; col++)
            {
                g.drawRect(35*row, 35 * col , 35, 35);
                if(maze[row][col].visited)
                {
                    //t.start();
                    g.fillRect(35*row, 35 * col , 35, 35);
                    //t.setDelay(5000);                 
                }
            }
        }
        repaint();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Maze p = new Maze(10);
        p.generator();
        p.adjlist();
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setTitle("Maze");
        f.add(p);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(700, 700);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p.DFS(new Cell(1,5));
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}

    }
```

The cell class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Cell{
    public int row, column;
    boolean visited;
    ArrayList<Cell> neighbor;

    public Cell(int i, int j)
    {
        row = i;
        column = j;
        visited = false;
        neighbor = new ArrayList<Cell>();
    }

    public int getRow()
    {
        return this.row;
    }

    public int getCol()
    {
        return this.column;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return this.row + " " + this.column;
    } 
  }
```

Comment: What's wrong with `Thread.sleep(ms)`?

Comment: where exactly would i put that i already try it but it did not change anything @JimGarrison

Comment: Clearly either the value you gave (in _milliseconds_) is too small, or you put the `sleep()` call in the wrong place.  Show what you did.  There's no `sleep()` call in the code you posted.

Comment: hey sorry i have edited it i had put the Thread.sleep right after the repaint is called @JimGarrison

Comment: hey i got the answer you were right i had the thread in the wrong place thanks @JimGarrison

Comment: Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For quick and efficient help, please post [mcve]. Your question basically boils down to adding delay to slow down swing gui updates, so all the information about DFS is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

The following code demonstrates the use of `SwingWorker` to demonstrate performing long tasks (in your case dfs search) which update the gui. 
Specific dfs information was removed because they are not relevant:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Maze extends JPanel {

    private final Cell [][] maze;
    private final int dims;
    private static final int SIZE = 35;

    public Maze(int dim) {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension( dim*SIZE,dim*SIZE));
        dims = dim;
        maze = new Cell[dims][dims];
    }

    public void generator()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0;j < maze[0].length; j++)
            {
                maze[i][j] = new Cell(i,j);
                //set some arbitrary initial date
                if(i%2 ==0 && j%2 ==0) {
                    maze[i][j].setVisited(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void DFS()
    {
        new DFSTask().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) //override paintComponent not paint
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (int row = 0; row < maze.length; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < maze[0].length; col++)
            {
                g.drawRect(SIZE*row, SIZE * col , SIZE, SIZE);
                if(maze[row][col].visited)
                {
                    g.fillRect(SIZE*row, SIZE * col , SIZE, SIZE);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Maze p = new Maze(10);
        p.generator();
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(p);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        p.DFS();
    }

    //use swing worker perform long task
    class DFSTask extends SwingWorker<Void,Void> {

        private static final long DELAY = 1000;
        private final Random rand = new Random();

        @Override
        public Void doInBackground() {
            dfs();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void done() { }

        void dfs() { //simulates long process that repeatedly updates gui

            while (true){ //endless loop, just for demonstration
                //update info
                int row = rand.nextInt(dims);
                int col = rand.nextInt(dims);
                maze[row][col].setVisited(! maze[row][col].isVisited());
                repaint(); //update jpanel
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(DELAY); //simulate long process
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }
    }
}

class Cell{

    private final int row, column;
    boolean visited;

    public Cell(int i, int j)
    {
        row = i;
        column = j;
        visited = false;
    }

    int getRow() {  return row; }

    int getColumn() {return column; }

    boolean isVisited() { return visited; }

    void setVisited(boolean visited) {  this.visited = visited;}

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return row + " " + column;
    }
}
```

For more information about using `SwingWorker` see [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

---

[image]